# Page Contents showing in Footer Area

Tags: plugins, menus, pages, footer

I am using Parallax Theme with the updated & current version of Wordpress, Elementor Plugin. I have created Custom Menu currently with 2 Pages. My page contents keep showing all the details in the Footer area, which is a big trouble and issue for me to resolve at this moment. Kindly have a look at the mentioned Link: https://flipsite.in/services/
My whole page contents showing in the Footer area. And I can't seem to remove that or I don't find the option. Any help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: Check your site, it showes "The site can't be reached" error.

Comment: Unless you've written code yourself to do any of this then you need to contact the theme and plugin developers for help. If you did write code please include and describe it so users here can help. This forum isn't appropriate for troubleshooting issues with 3rd-party code.

Answer (score 0):

you can add the following code in the Additional CSS to make this not show anymore:

```
.widget-column-3 div.elementor.elementor-36 {
display:none !important;
}
```

Let me know if this works or not. I would like to help you with this :)

Comment: Man! You earned my Respect! Hats off to you. Your one code saved my DAY. Thanks a TON! To be honest I was researching all over and even on the Plugins Developer FAQ section. Even they don't have a proper answer. Thanks again for the absolute resolution to my Problem. :)

Comment: Strange. But to let you know.... The error got removed only from my Services page. But still stays on the other page. Any suggestions?

Comment: Hi, Can you provide me login information so i can remove them all for you? thank you. :)

Comment: Hi Afnan, I already switched my Theme to a different one. And this one looks great and works just fine with Elementor. But I would like to keep in touch with you for any future reference.

Comment: Ok that's great. :)

Comment: Hey Man, I need your help with a Carousel. Mail me I guess. I am online. flipsite.in@gmail.com

Comment: just emailed you.